# eCryptfs - Cannot decrypt filenames

Tags: linux, ecryptfs

I have encrypted data on an external HD mounted on `/home/username/.Data`.
I am trying to decrypt it to `/home/username/Data`.

Although I can successfully read the files contents, I cannot manage to decrypt the filenames.

Here is what I am trying:

```
$ sudo ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek
Passphrase: 
Inserted auth tok with sig [aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa] into the user session keyring
Inserted auth tok with sig [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb] into the user session keyring

$ sudo mount -t ecryptfs /home/username/.Data /home/username/Data        
Passphrase: 
Select cipher: 
 1) aes: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 2) blowfish: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 56
 3) des3_ede: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 24; max keysize = 24
 4) twofish: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 5) cast6: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 6) cast5: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 5; max keysize = 16
Selection [aes]: 
Select key bytes: 
 1) 16
 2) 32
 3) 24
Selection [16]: 2
Enable plaintext passthrough (y/n) [n]: 
Enable filename encryption (y/n) [n]: y
Filename Encryption Key (FNEK) Signature [aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]: bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
Attempting to mount with the following options:
  ecryptfs_unlink_sigs
  ecryptfs_fnek_sig=bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
  ecryptfs_key_bytes=32
  ecryptfs_cipher=aes
  ecryptfs_sig=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  Mounted eCryptfs
```

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS** and **ecryptfs-utils 104-0ubuntu1**.

Any ideas to solve it?

Comment: Maybe this is the same problem as https://askubuntu.com/questions/566280/ecryptfs-cannot-decrypt-filenames/1042125#1042125

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed the probable problem buried there: You said "The external HD was encrypted some months ago, with an older version of Ubuntu."

Newer versions of eCryptfs do not always work on data encrypted with older versions. It's not fully backwards-compatible. You should decrypt the data using the original version that encrypted it.

Or, it's possible you're not using the right key for the filename encryption (fnek), double-check the key and look into the mount options `ecryptfs_fnek_sig=(fnek_sig)` and even `ecryptfs_sig=(fekek_sig)`.

Comment: I guess I am using the right key for the filename encryption because I can decrypt the name of the upmost directory. But when I manage this, the directory is inaccessible, and vice versa.